# Is it possible to access the functions for the PDF overlay bezel in Safari via keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, safari, pdf

When hovering the mouse pointer at the bottom of a PDF file being displayed within the Safari browser window, you get a set of 4 icons for Zoom Out, Zoom In, Open in… and Save To Downloads:

[image: Safari PDF hover menu]

I would like to be able to access the "Open in…" function via a keyboard shortcut, but can't seem to find the related item in any Safari menu. Is this possible to do?